# How to access a stage variable in a custom build task running inside that stage in azure pipelines yaml

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a variable defined inside my stage like below

**Doesn't work**

```
- stage: Stage 1
  variables:
    environment: Production

  jobs:
    -job:Job 1
     steps:
       - task: CustomTask_Powershell@1
         inputs:
           foo: bar
```

What's the right way to access the variable **environment** inside the powershell script implementation (.ps1) of the CustomTask_Powershell task that we own?

If I try `$(environment)`, it doesn't work and errors out as failed to recognize cmdlet

**Works:**

If I explicitly pass it as an environment variable as part of the task and then try to access it as `$env:environment`, then it works but I'm trying to find a way to not have to pass it explicitly as env if possible.

```
- stage: Stage 1
  variables:
    environment: Production

  jobs:
    -job:Job 1
     steps:
       - task: CustomTaak_Powershell
         inputs:
           foo: bar
         env:
           environment: $(environment)
```

What does `Get-VstsTaskVariable` do? Can that be used? Is there any other option to access the stage variable inside the task?

Answer (score -1):

In a PowerShell best task you can use the VstsTaskSdk to access any variable that weren't explicitly passed to the task.

The method you found `Get-VstsTaskVariable`, is the way to go. It provides a way to request the value of any variable, even of it wasn't explicitly passed to the task. This way tasks get a bit more trust than when you try to access variables from a normal script file that's called from your pipeline.

Simply call:

```
$environment = get-vststaskvaseable -name "environment"
```

Most variables are also registered as an environment variable, but they'all uppercased and any non alphanumerical value will be replaced by an underscore:

```
$environment = $env:ENVIRONMENT
```

The 3rd version to pass the variable in would be to explicitly declare the `environment` as an input to the task:

In task.json, add:

```
inputs": [
    {
      "defaultValue": "$(environment)"
      "label": "Environment",
      "name": "environment",
      "required": false,
      "type": "string"
    },
```

In your task you would then call:

```
$environment = get-vstsinput -name "environment" `
    -default (get-vststaskvaseable -name "environment)
```

And in your YAML:

```
    - task: CustomTask_Powershell@1
         inputs:
           foo: bar
           environment: $(environment)
```

Or omit the value to use the default:

```
    - task: CustomTask_Powershell@1
         inputs:
           foo: bar
```